# Why do `Distribution` classes in PyroPPL have a `log_prob()` method but not a `prob()` method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, probabilistic-programming

In PyroPPL, there exists an abstract `Distribution` class  that has a `sample()` method and a `log_prob()` method. The `log_prob()` method allows you to evaluate the log probability density for the distribution for a given scalar or array of values. I'm surprised that there is no `prob()` method though. This means that whenever you wish to evaluate the probability density you need to daisy chain a `log_prob()` method and a `exp()` method. What is the reason for not having a `prob()` method? Is it right to assume that evaluating probability densities for a given distribution would be a common operation?

I am fairly new to PPL's so is this a common choice in other PPL's?